# Blazor - Form Validation Unable to Read

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a simple Blazor form.  When I run the application if I type into the fields and press submit then I get `"field is required"`.  I am not sure why.  If I open up my note pad type in some words and copy and paste those into the fields then it works fine.  Is this a bug with Blazor in Debug Mode or am I doing something wrong?

```
@page "/" @using SBShared.Models @using SBSender.Services @inject IQueueService queue

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EditForm Model="@person" OnValidSubmit="@PublishMessage">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <InputText id="firstName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="person.FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <InputText id="lastName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="person.LastName" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> </EditForm>

@code{
    private PersonModel person = new PersonModel();

    private async Task PublishMessage()
    {
        await queue.SendMessageAsync(person, "personqueue");
        person = new PersonModel();
    } }
```

Comment: Rebuild your project then run and try and let me tell whats result now.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question

> Is this a bug with Blazor in Debug Mode or am I doing something wrong?"

I respectfully suggest that were it the former, it would have been found a long time ago.

So here's a slightly different version of your test page - it's now self contained with `PersonModel` defined - and, it works as advertised.

```
@page "/PersonTest"
<h3>PersonTest</h3>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EditForm Model="@person" OnValidSubmit="@PublishMessage">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <InputText id="firstName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="person.FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <InputText id="lastName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="person.LastName" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code{
    private PersonModel person = new PersonModel();

    private async Task PublishMessage()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        person = new PersonModel();
    }

    public class PersonModel
    {
        [Required] public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can see it working [here on my test site](https://blazor-starter.azurewebsites.net/persontest).

In the code above I've added a `Required` attribute to `FirstName`.  You need to review what attributes you have on fields in `PersonModel`.  "field is required" should also tell you which field.

Post a copy of `PersonModel` if you're stuck.

Comment: Hmmm strange. I get the same error with this version.  It must be on my end with my PC.  This happens with other websites sometimes too.  thank you for the detailed explanation.  I will give it a try on a different computer and see if that is the problem.  Maybe I have a Chrome extension enabled that messes with the UTF setting.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you try to launch the project, the page get prerendered. If you don't want that then you have to manually make it false by adding this at the top of that razor page:

```
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))
```

Comment: Add this at the top of that razor  page , because each time you try to luch the project when the page get prerendered if u don`t want that then u have to manually  make it false .

Comment: Please [edit] the answer with those details